# Link ignoring jquery to show sub nav

Tags: jquery, firefox

I've created a menu with a link that when you click it, it display a sub nav. This works fine on all browsers bar Firefox.

On clicking the link, it actually goes to the page rather than popping open the sub nav. Here's my jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $('.expander').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.expanded').first().toggle();
    });  

});
});
</script>
```

Any idea's why it would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `event` is `undefined` declare it in function just like this:-

```
 $('.expander').click(function(event) { //here
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).next('.expanded').first().toggle();
});
```

and if you are using `jQuery(function($) {` you dont need `$(document).ready(function() {` you should remove it.